# Why do I see edges from the other side while I'm in the top view

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, edges, 2d

If I'm in the 3d perspective then its fine, like u see here

[image]

But if I click on the "Z" so it's in the 2d perspective then it shows me the edges from the other side and I've literally found nothing why this keeps happening

[image]

Comment: Hi :). Your model seems to be very small, might be a problem with too high clipping range (top right in your screenshot)